# Activity A->B->C->A. How to get B's data at onActivityResult of A

Tags: android

I have three activities, call them A, B, and C. A is the parent activity of both B and C. Here are all possible activity flows.

1. A -> B -> press back or up button in action bar -> A.
2. A -> C -> press back or up button in action bar -> A.
3. A -> B -> C -> press back -> B.
4. A -> B -> C -> press up button in action bar -> A.

Both B and C can modify data that stored in A. So I make B and C send the modified data back to A by an intent, and use A's `onActivityResult` to update those data.

The problem is in flow 4, if B modifies some data, how can I send those modifications back to A? Should I pass them to C and make C send them back to A while C absolutely do not need those data?

**Update**

I found that in flow 4. Activity A's `onActivityResult` do not receive the returned `Intent`, the `Intent` parameter is always `null`, so we can't pass any data from C to A.

Originally I think A will receive C's `Intent`, so I can pass B's data to C then to A, but it's wrong. Activity A do not receive any `Intent` in flow 4.

Now I decide to change the up button's action, make it same as back button, so flow 4 will gone.

Comment: I also faced same issue many times, I handles this scenario in following way. Register a broadcast in activity A in onCreate() and unregister in onDestroy(). From activity C send roadcast with same Intent Action. It's work pretty good for me, but I doubt this is the correct solution. Hope some else jump into this with better solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in flow 4.

just need modifies data in B,no need to pass data to other activity.

call `setResult()` before B finished like other flow.it will return to A successful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the direct answer to the question, but recommendation :

When there is high interaction between Activities or need of too many activities, instead of too many activities or activity transactions , try to use **Fragments**.

**Using Interfaces (same/similar to JAVA) is the magic wand of the fragments**.
Use of fragmentation makes coding as easy as swapping the pages literally (Damned useful).

Here are the useful links : (You can copy, paste this code and can manipulate according to your requirements)

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html
2. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html